# v-checkbox is selected by default after second call to service

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have an issue and any help will be appreciated
I have this loop with checkboxes

```
<div v-for="(check, i) in alarms" :key="check.value">
  <v-checkbox
    v-if="check.contenido"
    v-model="checksModels[i]"
    :label="'Baja ' + check.contenido"
    :value="check"
  />
</div>
```

and the function that fetch the elements is this one

```
async fetchAlarms () {
    this.loading = true
    const alarmsAuhors = this.$axios.$get(`/service/getalarms/5`)
    const alarmsThemes = this.$axios.$get(`/service/getalarms/6`)
    const [resAuthors, resThemes] = await Promise.all([alarmsAuhors, alarmsThemes])
    this.alarms = [...resAuthors, ...resThemes]
    this.tipo5 = Boolean(resAuthors.length)
    this.tipo6 = Boolean(resThemes.length)
    this.loading = false
},
```

in the data I have both variables

```
  data: () => ({
    checksModels: [],
    alarms: [],
  }),
```

alarms fetch the results of the axios calls (everything is normal) the first time.
But if I launch the fetchAlarms () for the second time the checkboxes are checked even when the checksModels where I save the selected elements is empty.
Anyone knows how can I uncheck them.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What is the structure of `resThemes`? Maybe you need a deep copy? Are you sure otherwise that your `checksModels` state is empty? Double check with the Vue devtools.

Comment: I see that your structure is different from this doc, but might still be relevant somehow: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

Comment: alarms fetch the results from service and checkModels receive the checkboxes selected. On the screenshot you can see that its empty and there are two options selected

Comment: How do you reset it? There are some caveats with Vue2 that require you to use `$set` for arrays.

Comment: there is another function that once you press confirm that, between other things, call again to fetchAlarms()

Comment: As @kissu said, there are reactivity issues in Vue 2. Try using the `this.$set`. [More on Vue2 reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

Comment: It's not "issues" per-se, just JS limitations when using Vue2 (no proxies) mainly.